# Standard Manager not picking a Concurrent Program in Oracle Applications R 12.1.3

Tags: oracle

We got a request from a user that the program he submitted is not being picked up the concurrent manager:

Phase of the program is "Inactive "
Status of the program is "No Manager"

This program has 
1. no "Request Type" 
2. is not Included in any Concurrent Manager specialization rules 
3. is not Excluded from Standard Manager as well.

But still it is not getting picked up by Standard Manager. Could not understand what the issue could be.

Can anyone please suggest what the issue could be as I am not an expert in Sysadmin tasks in R12.

Regards,
Aditya.